# "tshark: There are no interfaces on which a capture can be done" in Amazon Linux AMI

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, wireshark, packet-capture, tshark

My goal is to capture packets with tshark in Amazon Linux AMI. While typing **tshark** in the command line there's an error:

```
"tshark: There are no interfaces on which a capture can be done"
```

How to implement the solution from [Wireshark setup Linux for nonroot user](http://ask.wireshark.org/questions/7976/wireshark-setup-linux-for-nonroot-user)

```
$ sudo apt-get install wireshark
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure wireshark-common 
$ sudo usermod -a -G wireshark $USER
$ gnome-session-quit --logout --no-prompt
```

in Amazon Linux AMI (it's not Ubuntu)? Thanks.

Comment: I thinkt hat magic group stuff is debian-ism meaning you can't duplicate it on a RH-based system as-such. I don't know that there is any similar mechanism on RH-based distributions.

Answer (score 0):

Run tshark with root priveleges.  See if this lists possible capture interfaces.

```
$ sudo tshark -D
```